# TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, icons

I can't seem to get the icons to display under Windows 7 and I really miss this from Windows XP.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Please read all the answers... The answer of Ralph Cowling and JohanKirsh helped me.

Comment: This simpler fix worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186529/4505142

Answer (score 555, accepted):

Windows can only show a limited number of Overlay Icons ([15 total, 11 after what Windows uses](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlnotshowing)).  Programs like [Office Groove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Groove), [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28storage_provider%29), [Mozy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozy), [Carbonite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonite_%28online_backup%29), etc, will hijack a bunch of the 11 possible overlay icons (boy would it be nice if Microsoft upped the number of these as the number of applications that use them seem to increase and increase)...

You can see what overlays are set up, and change them (at your own risk) in the registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

If you are using [TortoiseCVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseCVS) (and have nothing else using overlay icons), you will get a couple of [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) Icons, and all of your TortoiseCVS icons.  This is because the overlay icons are used in alphabetical order. Again, at your own risk (editing the registry may blow up your computer, yada, yada, yada -- and if you are reading Stack Overflow and using Windows and haven't edited the registry, you are a rare beast indeed), feel free to rename them (I suggest putting numbers in front of the ones you want to use and "z_"'s prefixed to the ones you don't need).  The TortoiseSVN Shell extensions are nicely named so you know what they do, the TortoiseCVS extensions are not.  After looking through the source code, I found the pertinent information:

- **TortoiseCVS0** - *In CVS*
- **TortoiseCVS1** - *Not in CVS*
- **TortoiseCVS3** - *Conflicted*
- **TortoiseCVS4** - *In CVS readonly*
- **TortoiseCVS5** - *Ignored*
- **TortoiseCVS6** - *Added*
- **TortoiseCVS7** - *Deleted*
- **TortoiseCVS8** - *Locked*

Comment: This was the answer for me.  I had Mozy and DropBox installed and simply prefixed each of their entries under the "ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers" key with "z_".  I logged off and then back on, and the Tortise overlay icons reappeared.  I'm using the 64-bit version of both Win7 and TortiseSVN.

Comment: This was the answer for me as well, I had installed Gladinet, which along with Carbonite had taken up my icons.

Comment: awesome! worked for me!  I popped a "z" in front of the DropBox related icons, restarted, and boom, there they are.

Comment: That was the solution for me. I just deleted some unused overlays like offline files.

Comment: dude! 1+ , I had noticed it happened when I installed Office 2010 and reported it (with no luck of course). Thanks.

Comment: Restarting or logging out is not necessary, simply end and run explorer.exe.

Comment: had garbled values in the registry, but run through my installed programs, just to find Microsoft's Live Uploader. removed, rebooted and viola! thanks alot

Comment: I just installed TortoiseSVN fresh, and it's putting numbers in front of the registry entries now.

Comment: Looks like Tortoise implemented this workaround out of the box: its identifiers are prefixed with numbers. However, I still don't see them (while I do see Dropbox's icons...)

Comment: Beware: explorer seems to load the overlays in ASCII order, but the registry editor displays them in some other (slightly different) order. Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to verify the order the registry keys are accessed when starting explorer.exe.

Comment: I just had this happen to me and it looks like TortoiseSVN started an arms race: Microsoft Skydrive icons start with a space(!): " Skydrive1", Box.com icons start with "000", Avast! names its overlay "00Avast", etc.

Comment: Tortoise implemented this workaround out of the box: its identifiers are prefixed with numbers. If you have no other program using names prefixed with numbers (or spaces) and you still don't see overlays, try the solution proposed by spoulson (see below).  It works with various versions of Tortoise.

Comment: As others have pointed out Tortoise now adds numbers to bounce their overlays to the top. However at least SkyDrive and Adobe Creative Cloud add spaces to the start of their key names bouncing them to the top of the list. Hard to see in regedit, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Informative answer, but... before trying this, try starting and stopping explorer.exe as suggested below by JohanKirsh. Having only just migrated to Win7 and downloaded the latest TortoiseSVN release, this alone was sufficient to reinstate the overlay icons for me.

Comment: The 15 overlays limit is still in Windows 8.1. :/

Comment: @LeighRiffel - End process did not work for me. Btw, if someone wants to try your approach, here are the steps. Run taskmgr.exe or task manager > processes tab > select explorer.exe > kill. Then click file option > new task > enter explorer.exe > ok.

Comment: I had to select 'Upgrade Working Copy' at the root of my working copy (after upgrading from v 1.6 to 1.8). And changed the registry as per comment above. And I did a repair on 1.8.

Comment: Dropbox also tries to force its icons to the top of the registry priority by enclosing them in quotes like `"DropboxExt1"`

Comment: Scroll down and check my answer guys it worked like a charm for more than 22 different computers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7/26519913#26519913

Comment: As always SO gives me the answer I need. Kudos!!

Comment: just rename it and push a bunch of whitespaces infront + restart explorer and you are done.

Comment: Is the same limitation of 15 overlay icons in Windows 10 as well?

Comment: After installation of skype and MS one Drive, this issue started and I noticed both created many entries in the registry. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dropbox has changed their naming scheme again, to force them to the top, by adding 3 spaces at the start of the names.

Comment: My forecast for 2019-2020, based on the current trend and personal research, is that Dropbox will be using 8 to 11 spaces.

Comment: @LeighRiffel - a good point, but it isn't necessary to do something "unusual" like kill explorer. [Though you are correct that that is all that is needed for this situation, so is good for people to know.] What I recommend: Sign out of Windows, then sign back in. Quick, easy to remember, and is a more broadly useful technique, as it resets more than just explorer.

Comment: It's ridiculous that Microsoft set a (non-adjustable) limitation on the number of overlay icons. With Dropbox and TortoiseGit installed, I prefer the selection and order of icons [this blog post mentions](https://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit/).

Comment: It's 2020, and I still have to manually remove the Dropbox overlays (with now 3 leading spaces) every couple of weeks to see my SVN icon overlays...

Answer (score 219):

### Halt ye!

Before doing anything to your registry or similar procedures listed in Kris Erickson's (excellent) answer or the ones below, there's something to consider...

***Are you on a network drive?***

If so, go to Tortoise SVN settings (right click any folder > TortoiseSVN > Settings), then go to 'Icon Overlays'

Make sure you've checked 'Network Drives' as pictured:

[image]

By default on a fresh Tortoise install, network drives don't have the icons added.

This solved the problem for us. If this fails for you then obviously you can go through the (slightly) more involved solutions listed here.

Comment: You rocked my world. that fixed this annoying problem. Might use useful to stop the TSVNCache service after you do it so the icons load correctly

Comment: I have my SVN in a Win7 Fusion VM on a Mac and the repository is in the host documents folder through the Fusion sharing options.  This solved my icons not showing.

Comment: Great! A TrueCrypt volume seems to be handled as a network drive.

Comment: similar to WMIF fixed my issue when using an OS X drive from Parallels

Answer (score 121):

Also restarting your PC is not needed. Instead restart explorer.exe:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd>.
2. Click the **Processes** tab.
3. Right-click on **explorer.exe**.
4. Select **End Process**.
5. Click **End Process** button.
6. Click the **Applications** tab.
7. Right-click.
8. Click **New Task (Run)**.
9. Set **Open** to: `explorer`
10. Click **OK**.

Windows Explorer has restarted and the TortoiseSVN icons reappear.

Comment: Killing and restarting **explorer.exe** is cumbersome (it's slow to restart, and it doesn't restart all the child processes that you also killed). Try killing [TSVNCache.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19454812/740639) instead, then refreshing your Windows Explorer window by pressing F5 to see if the icons return.

Comment: Right-clicking the taskbar and clicking 'Task Manager' will ALSO bring up the Task Manager.

Comment: you can also do it from command prompt:
1. taskkill /f -im explorer.exe
2. start explorer.exe

Comment: You can do this gracefully. Open the start menu and then hold ctrl+shift while right clicking on it; "exit explorer" will appear as an option. You'll still need to open up task manager (e.g. using ctrl+alt+delete) to restart it though! This is on Windows 7; on Windows 8 I think you can still do it by ctrl+shift+right click on the task bar.

Comment: GIT Tortoise or SVN Tortoise Icon Overlay Settings need to get actiavted once we do installation of Tortoise setup.
So, by re-starting Explorer, We give it a chance to run.

Comment: In Windows 10 there is a "Restart" option for Windows Explorer in Task Manager. Worked instantaneously for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me too. It seems that explorer needed to be restarted after installation of TortoiseSVN in order for explorer to show the icon overlays.

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated. (Though nice to know.) Just sign out of windows and sign back in. Should only take a few seconds, and is easy to remember. Its a middle ground between (slow) Reboot, and doing multiple steps like this answer :)

Answer (score 68):

I, too, lost my overlays after upgrading to 1.6.8 on Windows 7 x64.  I only installed the x64 version and not the 32-bit version.  To fix, I ran a repair with the original installer and rebooted.  The overlays displayed normally thereafter.

Comment: From the TortoiseSVN lead developer (2010-04-17): "You might have to do a repair install (start the installer again, then choose 'repair') after you've updated to 1.6.8. Otherwise the overlay icons might not show up properly. Sorry for the inconvenience."

Comment: If repair install does not work, just follow this cycle as many times as required: 1) Uninstall 2) Reboot 3) Install 4) Reboot

Comment: Definitely try this before any regedits. When doing a repair on TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, you won't need to reboot if you let it shut down apps before repairing. I had a new Windows 7 32-bit system and installed TortoiseSVN 1.7.1 on it after installing Subclipse 1.8.2. (Maybe the order of installation caused the problem, because a coworker did the reverse and had no issues.) The TortoiseSVN icons didn't show up on any source-controlled folders, except when I put them into the Recycle Bin (what the...?). Doing a repair just once fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem with Windows 8.1 and Tortoise SVN 1.8.1. Updating from TSVN 1.8.1 to 1.8.4 didn't help, I still had the problem. Once 1.8.4 was installed, re-running the installer and choosing the Repair option fixed my issue

Answer (score 41):

I [resolved it](http://blog.magerquark.de/2010-06/repair-broken-tortoisesvn-explorer-overlay-icons-on-windows-7-64-bit/) by using Autoruns from Sysinternals.

1. Run [Autoruns](http://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe)
2. In the 'Explorer' tab, scroll down to the 'OverlayIconIdentifier' and 'ShellOverlayIconIdentifier' entries
3. Un-tick unwanted overlays (such as most of any Dropbox, SkyDrive etc.)
4. Restart Explorer.exe

[image: Autoruns screenshot showing Overlay Icons entries]

Comment: I've tried every answer up there, but none of them works. Then I downloaded autoruns and did some setting, the icon finally show! Thank you a lot!

Comment: As davido said "beats opening up regedit" Autoruns quickly lets you enable/disable overlays. Once SkyDrive overlays were disabled, Tortoise Git/SVN showed all the familiar overlays again. I furthermore used it to disable a few other overlays (e.g. DropDox) that didn't find necessary.

Comment: this worked great for me. but drop box placed itself back in front after a couple of weeks. So i had to reapply this answer. starred for future.

Comment: This is a much nicer, more elegant solution

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue as the OP: Win 7 (x64), TortoiseSVN (x64), and DropBox (x86). The info from some of the other answers gave me all the info. I've only ever had the x64 version of TSVN installed on this machine.

In my case TSVN and DropBox were installed the same day I did the OS install and the overlays worked fine until a couple of days ago. I did nothing involving changing settings for either app to cause them to stop working.

Here is what I had in the icon overlay registry section after the problem started (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`):

1. DropboxExt1
2. DropboxExt2
3. DropboxExt3
4. EnhancedStorageShell
5. Offline Files
6. SharingPrivate
7. TortoiseAdded
8. TortoiseConflict
9. TortoiseDeleted
10. TortoiseIgnored
11. TortoiseLocked
12. TortoiseModified
13. TortoiseNormal
14. TortoiseReadOnly
15. TortoiseUnversioned

I verified that only the overlays corresponding to the first 11 entries display in Explorer. When I modified the order of above entries by adding 'z' to the start of some of them, again only the first 11 overlays (under the updated order) would display.

With the above I had everything I needed to solve the problem (either rename or or delete entries so that the TSVN entries I want working are <= #11 on the list). Below deals with wondering why this suddenly happened.

I know that based on the overlays that worked prior to a couple of days ago, keys 1-3, 7-9, 12-13 were all <= 11 in the list (not sure if overlay #14 ever worked since I never had files w/ read-only status. #15 never worked on this machine so i know it was never in the top 11). I also assume the block of TSVN keys move up/down in unison, therefore they were bumped down either two or three places (* see below). This implies that 2-3 items were added between the DropBox & TSVN blocks. The three that are there now are added by Windows and I would assume they'd be there as soon as the OS installed.

Is the list of 15 overlays determined at run-time? Seems like the overlay handlers might sometimes tell the windows shell that there are no icons to add to the list. Possibly some settings I messed with a couple of days ago related to file sharing and file encryption caused some of those items at the 4-6 spots to become "activated" and push the SVN ones down.

In the end I deleted a couple of entries and moved some, so my final list looks like this:

1. DropboxExt1
2. DropboxExt2
3. DropboxExt3
4. SharingPrivate (i want this to show up)
5. TortoiseAdded
6. TortoiseConflict
7. TortoiseDeleted
8. TortoiseModified
9. TortoiseNormal
10. TortoiseReadOnly
11. TortoiseUnversioned
12. zOffline Files (i don't use Sync Center, or "Offline Files" so I don't care about this)
13. zEnhancedStorageShell (don't really know what Enhanced Storage is, don't think I need this)

Answer (score 19):

They display fine here. Are you using the 64-bit version of Windows 7 along with the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN? If so, then they will only show up in the 32-bit Explorer (or in the CFDs of 32-bit applications). You can install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions side-by-side, though.

Comment: Same for me - I've seen no issues with TortoiseSVN on Windows 7. I'm using 32-bit versions of both, however.

Comment: That could be why, will have to download the 64bit version and see

Comment: I have 32 & 64 bit TortoiseSVN installed on Win7 Ultimate 64-bit. I get the folder icons, but not the file icons. All the registry entries have been prepended with "z_" except for the 9 TortoiseSVN ones.

Answer (score 14):

Two other possible solutions:

1. Kill TSVNCache.exe and let it re-launch.  This has caused my shell overlay icons to re-appear on several occasions.
2. If you've recently upgraded TortoiseSVN from a previous version, you may need to upgrade your working copy.  This can be done by right-clicking on your project folder and choose "SVN Upgrade working copy" from the context menu.

Comment: i had a similar problem killing TSVNCache.exe helped me in resolving. Please do not do anything with  windows registry.

Comment: I thought "upgrade" was a strange term for SVN, should've known it meant something other than version control. Thanks for #2: its a really good point that the metadata could change on big gaps between versions.

Comment: My problem was that, for some reason, TSVNCache.exe was not running. I simply launched it and the overlay icons reappeared.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest complaining to Microsoft regarding the ridiculously low icon overlay limit.  If enough of us complain, perhaps they'll fix the true root cause of this problem:

See comments at bottom of page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123(VS.85).aspx

Give Microsoft Windows 7 team feedback on this issue:
http://mymfe.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Feedback.aspx?formID=195

Answer (score 9):

My icons had disappeared too. The registry fixes did not work for me either.

This is how I got them back:

1. install the latest version of [TortoiseOverlays](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/TortoiseOverlays/)
2. restart explorer.exe

Comment: +1 This worked for me even though it was only some projects that weren't displaying icons (and hence I assumed, not an issue with Explorer's limited number of overlays).

Comment: Did you have some project on non-fixed drives? TortoiseOverlays adds the icons for Network Drives and the like too.

Comment: For me, TortoiseOverlays 1.0.15 worked with Tortoise SVN TortoiseSVN-1.7.11.23600, but not TortoiseSVN-1.8.1.24570  I spent an hour and a half installing/uninstalling the different Tortoise SVN clients figuring that out.  Hopefully, I can save someone else the lost time.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you just need to go to TortoiseSVN "settings", turn the icons off, click "apply", turn them back on.

Windows Start->All Programs->TortoiseSVN->Settings

[image]

Comment: +1 Try this before even thinking about touching the registry.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem for me. It turns out that the cause of the problem was the new JungleDisk 3.0, which rudely installs three overlays named "1Sync..." "2Sync..." and "3Sync..." pushing the Tortoise ones off the end.

Just delete those JungleDisk keys in the reg hive listed at the top (or prefix them with z_) and re-start the system and Tortoise should work fine again.

Given that this overlay limit exists in Windows and is easily hit with current tools, tool vendors really should ask during advanced installation if the user wants to install them. I have no need nor desire for the new "Sync" feature and don't really care for the tactic of stuffing the icons at the top of the list with clever naming. Shame on JungleDisk.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to change in Tortoise Settings the status cache to 'Default'? I had this problem with the overlay icon on folders because I had this option in 'Shell'.
The option is in Settings -> Icons overlay.

Maybe this could help you http://tortoisesvn.net/node/97

Comment: For some reason I had changed my status cache to None - changing it back to default brought the icons back. I also did the registry hack beforehand and prefixed the Groove entries with "z", but the status cache change was needed before my icons came back.

Comment: Turning Cache to off and applying then turning back to default fixes it every time for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, Dropbox overlays were starting with a " (quoted identifier) in the registry. I deleted all the " prefixes and restarted explorer.exe.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

Edit: I installed Windows 10 and this solution didn't work for me. So I just went to the same registry location and deleted all Google and SkyDrive records and restarted explorer.exe.

Second edit: After installing TortoiseGit it fixed everything without any customisation.

Comment: had to uninstall Dropbox and then stop and restart explorer. bye bye Dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

I just upgraded to TSVN 1.6.8.19260 on a WinXP and two Win7 machines. After upgrading, the overlay icons disappeared on all 3 machines. Under the above mentioned registry key, I only found the entry for offline files.
I simply had to reinstall/repair the TSVN installation and the icons reappeared after a reboot. I've never detected that behaviour in any previous TSVN version and I certainly installed TSVN everytime the same way with the same permissions.

Answer (score 4):

If you have recently upgraded Tortoise SVN, it may be because version 1.7 seems to need a new format for storing the status of files - in which case, you can right click the root folder of your repository in question, and use the Tortoise menu option of 'SVN Upgrade Working Copy'.

This resolved the problem for me.

Cheers
Matt

Answer (score 3):

To [complete Johannes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortise-svn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7/1057754#1057754), you can check [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/3d17b1339cd6cc9e), which mentions another cause (the first one being installing the 32bit client instead of the 64 one) (emphasis mine):

> Only more recent versions of TSVN and TCVS are able to share overlay icons, and **since Explorer has a limit of 14 overlay images in total with extraneous overlay icons
>   simply not showing up you might have too many**...
>
> If it's overlay icons are showing up you'd have to actually be using
>   the 32-bit Windows Explorer, which of course means you'll have to also
>   install a 32-bit version of TSVN.

The issue might come up when one install also first TortoiseVCS, because:

> Looking at what got installed in the filesystem and the registry, it looks like they tried to do what I do with my Shell extensions - install both 64 and 32 -bit versions, so that nobody says "I don't see my overlays/menus"! ;)
>
> Unfortunately, it looks like the registry entries for 32-bit got hosed, so the 32-bit extension DLL, even though present, does not have the correct registry entries.
>
> If in doubt I suggest to deinstall TCVS and TSVN.
>   Then install TSVN.
>   Maybe after installation reboot twice, not only once.
>   And if they still don't show up go to software control panel and choose to repair the installation. That did the trick for me with when upgrading from the previous to the current version.
>
> You should probably install the TortoiseXYZ variant you plan to use mainly first, to improve its chances to fall into one of those limited number of overlay icons slots before the TortoiseXYZ variant you use less.
>   **Always keep these limited number of overlay icon slots in mind when trying to analyze malfunctions**.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you install the 32bit version first it some how mucks up the 64bit version. On reinstalling windows 7 i just installed the 64bit version and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Tortoise from within a 32 bit Application on Windows 7 64 bit, you need to install both the 64bit and the 32bit versions of Tortoise. According to Tortoise's makers, this works fine. ([source](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads))

Comment: Tried this on Win7 x64 with TSVN 1.9.2 and the installer will not let me install the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Kris Erickson is right, vote him up. In my case the problem was installing TFS powertools , which adds explorer shell integration just like TSVN and TCVS. It adds another 5 overlays. Since they are prefixed with Tfs*, they take priority over Tortoise*. I also just prefixed the Tfs stuff with z_ and the TSVN overlays came back. No need to reboot/logoff though, just kill explorer.exe and start it again.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible problems and solutions

1. Limitation of number of usable overlay icons by Windows, refer to Kris Erickson's answer.
2. Inappropriate setting of TortoiseSVN, refer to Ralph Cowling's answer.
3. Known bug for updating from earlier version (pre 1.6.10), see [here.](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)
4. TortoiseSVN was not installed for all users, try to install with cmd like below, if all below three solutions don't work, I believe this method will save your life.

---

```
rem Set your own path.
set TOOL_ROOT=d:\Tools\TortoiseSVN-1.6.13.20954-win32-svn-1.6.16\tortoisesvn_1.6.16.21511
set PACKAGENAME=TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511-x64-svn-1.6.17.msi
set TOOL_INSTALLROOT="c:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN"

msiexec /i "%TOOL_ROOT%\%PACKAGENAME%" INSTALLDIR=%TOOL_INSTALLROOT% ALLUSERS=1 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 RebootYesNo=No REBOOT=ReallySupress /qb-

set ret=%ERRORLEVEL%

rem The installer seems to return same values as MSI
rem These codes mean that the product is properly installed, even though the code is not zero.
rem 1641 ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_INITIATED
rem 3010 ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED
if %ret% EQU 1641 set ret=0
if %ret% EQU 3010 set ret=0
if %ret% GTR 0 exit %ret%
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs the registry entries for Windows 7 64-bit, here they are. What was good for me as to remove the overlays for items not really used often: Drop Box, Google Drive, Microsoft Products, and just kept the overlays for Tortoise. These are all the overlays - nothing is removed.

** Caution ** Playing with the registry can make your system unstable. Be sure to backup your registry. See [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=backup%20registry%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) on various ways to backup your registry or registry setting(s).

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers]

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ AccExtIco1]

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ AccExtIco2]

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ AccExtIco3]

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ SkyDrivePro1 (ErrorConflict)]
    @="{8BA85C75-763B-4103-94EB-9470F12FE0F7}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ SkyDrivePro2 (SyncInProgress)]
    @="{CD55129A-B1A1-438E-A425-CEBC7DC684EE}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\ SkyDrivePro3 (InSync)]
    @="{E768CD3B-BDDC-436D-9C13-E1B39CA257B1}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt1"]
    @="{FB314ED9-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt2"]
    @="{FB314EDA-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt3"]
    @="{FB314EDD-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt4"]
    @="{FB314EDE-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt5"]
    @="{FB314EDB-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt6"]
    @="{FB314EDF-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt7"]
    @="{FB314EDC-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"DropboxExt8"]
    @="{FB314EE0-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\00avast]
    @="{472083B0-C522-11CF-8763-00608CC02F24}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\1EldosIconOverlay]
    @="{AF743E58-5357-404B-8314-32D2D8420F9D}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\1TortoiseNormal]
    @="{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\2TortoiseModified]
    @="{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\3TortoiseConflict]
    @="{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\4TortoiseLocked]
    @="{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\5TortoiseReadOnly]
    @="{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\6TortoiseDeleted]
    @="{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\7TortoiseAdded]
    @="{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\8TortoiseIgnored]
    @="{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\9TortoiseUnversioned]
    @="{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\EldosIconOverlay]
    @="{5BB532A2-BF14-4CCC-86B7-71B81EF6F8BC}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\EnhancedStorageShell]
    @="{D9144DCD-E998-4ECA-AB6A-DCD83CCBA16D}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GDriveBlacklistedOverlay]
    @="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D42}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GDriveSharedEditOverlay]
    @="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D44}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GDriveSharedViewOverlay]
    @="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D43}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GDriveSyncedOverlay]
    @="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D40}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GDriveSyncingOverlay]
    @="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\off0]
    @="{8E33AEC3-C5F2-43C4-B048-9E3EB19B1DD5}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\off1]
    @="{8E33AEC4-C5F2-43C4-B048-9E3EB19B1DD5}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\Offline Files]
    @="{4E77131D-3629-431c-9818-C5679DC83E81}"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\SharingPrivate]
    @="{08244EE6-92F0-47f2-9FC9-929BAA2E7235}"
```

Remember, these are for Windows 64-bit and you should take a backup of your registry be

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here (and some otherplaces), and what worked for me (after doing all of these, the registry changes are mandatory I think) was to change the setting for Icon Overlays\Status Cache from Default to Shell, and I also checked "Show overlays and context menu only in explorer".  Not sure which of those two did it but it works now.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Changing Status cache to Shell means you aren't seeing *recursive* icons. For example, if you add or change a file, you will see a different icon *on that file* (and maybe on the folder that directly contains that file, I don't remember), but **won't see a change icon on a higher-level folder**. Instead, you will see "up-to-date" icons on those higher-level folders, even though, somewhere down below, it is not up-to-date!  [Tested just now on TortoiseSVN 1.9.6 running on Windows 10 64-bit]

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to TSVN 1.6.8.19260 I had the same issue (no icons in Explorer), but in my case, there were NO entries at all for TSVN under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers. In my original install, I didn't included the additional icon sets, because I never use them (and I've never installed them in any previous upgrades).

I modified my installation, adding the additional icon sets, and my icons have magically reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

My main purpose was to get ICONs for TortoiseCVS.  Many of the suggestions did not work for me: uninstall reinstall; regedit by renaming; rebooting multiple times.  But what did work was to **install TortoiseSVN**.  This made the icons for TortoiseCVS work.  I checked out regedit. The SVN install put numbers in front of the icon names:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers]
1TortoiseNormal
2TortoiseModified
3TortoiseConflict
4TortoiseLocked
5TortoiseReadOnly
6TortoiseDeleted
7TortoiseAdded
8TortoiseIgnored
9TortoiseUnversioned
Groove Explorer Icon Overlay 1 (GFS Unread Stub)
Groove Explorer Icon Overlay 2 (GFS Stub)
Groove Explorer Icon Overlay 2.5 (GFS Unread Folder)
Groove Explorer Icon Overlay 3 (GFS Folder)
Groove Explorer Icon Overlay 4 (GFS Unread Mark)
SharingPrivate
TortoiseAdded
TortoiseConflict
TortoiseDeleted
TortoiseIgnored
TortoiseLocked
TortoiseModified
TortoiseNormal
TortoiseReadOnly
TortoiseUnversioned
zEnhancedStorageShell
zOffline Files
zSkyDrivePro1 (ErrorConflict)
zSkyDrivePro2 (SyncInProgress)
zSkyDrivePro3 (InSync)
```

Comment: I also need TortoiseCVS and tried to install TortoiseSVN.. didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem here with TortoiseSVN 1.6.16.  Icons were fine, but then I installed and uninstalled TortoiseGit and suddenly the TortoiseSVN icons stopped working.  Looking at the registry I discovered that uninstalling TortoiseGit also removed all overlay icons.  I simply reinstalled TortoiseSVN and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

editing the registry order worked for me. the entries already had #s before it. so it wasnt working. 
I realized the previous entries had spaces. so now my svn registry has a space,#,name

Answer (score 0):

A combination of solutions worked for me. I tried to kill and restart explorer.exe as suggested by @LeighRiffel. Did not work. I uninstalled dropbox because I rarely use it. Then, I tried the explorer thing again and it worked. Maybe you can reinstall dropbox after this and see if things are okay ? I don't care though.

Here are the steps: Run taskmgr.exe or task manager > processes tab > select explorer.exe > kill. Then click file option > new task > enter explorer.exe > ok.

Comment: No, as soon as you re-install dropbox, its overlays will take precedence *if* they are alphabetically-earlier. (As I write this, dropbox has THREE SPACES in front of each overlay name, so that they will win out over any "competing" overlay app that has fewer than 3 spaces starting each name.) Personally I solved this by adding more spaces in front of the SVN icons I use (via RegEdit). This will work until some update of Dropbox adds even more spaces. Insanity...

Answer (score 0):

When I checked out a new project from the repository, I did not see the icon overlays.

I started looking for solutions and came to this question.

While reading answers, I noticed the icon overlays appeared on my checkout project.

I guess it just took a few minutes for the icons to appear.

I thought this might be useful before people panic quickly and start editing the registry.

Comment: .. or people could log out of windows and log back in, which is a quick and easy way to be sure Windows is using recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the registry worked for me.

If its helpful to anyone, I initially prefixed "z_" to the entries in "ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers" that I wanted to move down. However that didn't seem to bring up the TortoiseSVN entries. It might be due to case sensitivity wherein lowercase "z" still precedes uppercase "T". Finally, prefixing with "Z_" instead did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is another reason why the icons wont be shown.
Today I made an update of my TortoiseSVN Client from 1.6.x to 1.10.x. After that the Icons of my Working copies were not displayed any more.
But it turns out that it has nothing to do with to many applications occupy the  possible icons. The reason was that the Working copies format was to old. **First you have to make a "SVN upgrade working copy" with your new installed client.**

You can read more about the details here: [SVN upgrade working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy)

Have a nice day