# tortoise svn folder icons not coming

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisecvs, tortoisemerge

I have been experiencing a problem with tortoise .

when i checked out the code the tortoise icons usually green or red on the folders are not coming.Any solution???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try also to repair the installation, if you upgraded from 1.6.8 or 1.6.9. Just re-launch the TortoisSVN installer and choose "Repair". There are known problems with overlay icons and TortoiseSVN upgrades (see [this blog post](http://tortoisesvn.net/majorupgrade)).

Comment: I have uninstalled the application and after restarting the machine i installed it again and now its working fine...Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem with Windows 8.1 and Tortoise SVN 1.8.1. Updating from TSVN 1.8.1 to 1.8.4 didn't help, I still had the problem. Once 1.8.4 was installed, re-running the installer and choosing the Repair option fixed my issue

Comment: It is actually the reboot that fixed the issue here, (temporarily). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26308182/14749

Answer (score 21):

### 1 - Check If Your TortoiseSVN Settings are Correct

Right-Click in an SVN Folder >> TortoiseSVN >> Settings
Select Icon Overlays:
 1. Status Cache to Default
 2. Drive Types: (SELECT) Network Drive, Fixed Drive

### 2 - Find out if there are too many Icon Sets installed in Windows

*Window allows up to 11 IconSets, if other programs like DropBox are installed they will hijack those spots*
**Since we are working in the registry, be careful not to edit things, unless you are sure!**

1. Run regedit
2. Navigate to:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS/EXPLORER/ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
3. If there are more than 11 Folders, then you have too many IconSets

   :: In my case, it was because of DropBox - the folder names were ("DropboxExt1","DropboxExt2") and my Tortoise was named (1TortoiseNormal,2TortoiseModified)
   --The problem is that Windows reads this and enables them based on alpha numeric order ('"' comes before '1' in the alphanumeric stack)

   **SOLUTION** : If you had the same problem as me, you can simply rename the Dropbox registry listings.  I renamed my Dropbox listings from('"DropboxExt1"') to ('X"DropboxExt1"'), just adding an 'X' to the beginning of the registry.
    >>Restart your machine to see the registry listing take effect.

Comment: It appears the space wars have begun :) Dropbox uses 1 space prefix, Google Drive now uses 2 spaces, so I had to bump my favourite TortoiseSVN icons to 3 spaces.

Comment: @si618 The worst part is that any average user wouldnt think their icons will drop off when you install new software

Comment: @si618:
My Tortoise Shell overlays just disappeared recently, so I took a look in the registry and saw that I had already added 2 extra spaces for Tortoise in the past to counter the 1 extra space of Dropbox, but the latest Dropbox update apparently has changed it to 3 extra spaces for Dropbox.
I have just renamed all Tortoise overlays to contain a 4 spaces prefix and it works again.

I wonder at how many spaces we will end up over the coming years.

Comment: @si618 - it is possible that updates from Dropbox or other icons servers have pushed to the front -- since i can't see your registry (nor would i want to) it's hard to know.  If you are comfortable, test uninstalling some of the other progs that have icon sets to see if any come back -- reinstall the progs.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. The location of ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers is
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers"

Answer (score 4):

If you have checked out your code onto a network, or removable drive, you need to set some preferences to see the icons.

Comment: `Settings` -> `Look and Feel` -> `Icon Overlays`.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link
http://tortoisesvn.net/node/97. I have also experienced simillar problem and the icon usually starts appearing after two or three reboots.

Also refer the following links

http://gavtaylor.co.uk/blog/missing-tortoise-svn-shell-icon-overlays

[TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `TortoiseSVN>Settings>Icon Overlays>Status Cache`.

If `default` is selected then change from default to `shell`. If `shell` is selected then change it from `shell` to `default`. it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on your platform? You need to install 64-bit TortoiseSVN if you want the TortoiseSVN Overlay icons in Windows Explorer, because Windows Explorer is 64-bit on Windows 64-bit.

see http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#nomenus

> Make sure you have installed the x64 version of TortoiseSVN if you're
>   using XP or Vista 64-bit. Since the explorer on those OS versions is a
>   64-bit application, it can not load the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN.
>
> You can still keep the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN installed on
>   those OS versions though: it will show up in the 32-bit applications
>   file-open/save dialogs of those applications.

Comment: So 32-bits apps don't run on 64-bit Windows? That's news to me.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Sorry, my answer wasn't clear in this point: You need 64-bit TortoiseSVN if you want the TortoiseSVN Overlay icons in Windows Explorer or generally in the Windows shell, because Windows Explorer is 64-bit on Windows 64-bit. Of course you can run 32-bit TortoiseSVN on Windows 64-bit, but then you can't use the shell extensions which are the main user interface for TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @CamiloMartin So if you want to use TortoiseSVN via Windows shell/Explorer on Windows 64-bit you need the 64-bit version: http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#nomenus

Comment: Ah, I thought Explorer could load 32-bit shell extensions. My bad :)

Answer (score -1):

In the recent versions of the TortoiseSVN, old `_svn` folders are deprecated. it's better to rename them to `.svn`.

```
attrib -h _svn
rename _svn .svn
attrib +h .svn
```