# Don't see status icons in windows explorer

Tags: svn, windows-7

i installed svn on my win7 machine but i don't see those colorfull icons in windows explorer showing things like file is already added in svn, file has changed etc etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same problem, appearing on only one of my working copies (I have many projects on my machine, and the rest were displaying icons normally).

I opened task manager, and ended the process `TSVNCache.exe`. Within a minute, it started up again, and when it did, I was able to refresh my view in Windows Explorer, and the tortoise svn icons appeared on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Select or configure the relevant options or choices for the type of presentation of folders and file names to you like list or thumb or large icon and then select the options for displaying indicators of different types of condition or state of the files. Depends on the options available in differing version of svn.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to rebuild your icon cache (kill explorer.exe, delete `IconCache.db` from `%APPDATA%\Local` and restart explorer.exe). But depending on the flavor of SVN you installed, you may not even have the shell extension stuff that provides them. TortoiseSVN should give you icons (sometimes only after a reboot after install), but some command-line-only distributions won't.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Subversion, or [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)? TortioseSVN is a Subversion client that is independent of the command line Subversion client. In fact, you don't even need the Subversion command line client installed to use TortoiseSVN (although I highly recommend everyone does so).

TortoiseSVN is a plugin to Windows Explorer and since it is attached to Windows Explorer, it can manipulate the icons in Windows Explorer to add a Subversion status mask to the icons.

By default, TortoiseSVN does not munge icons to anything but local drives since adding icons to network drives can slow it down, You can change that in the Tortoise configuration, though.