# SVN folder does not have green icon in Windows7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am setting up a repository, and for some reason when I create a repository, the directory does not change to displaying the common SVN checkbox.

Are there any common well-known mistakes that cause that?

I am using Windows7

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that's exactly your problem, but there is a common problem with the TortoiseSVN overlay icons not showing up in Windows 7:

- [TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 6):

Right click on a folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Icon overlays -> Exclude paths:

If there are green markers in the checked out subfolders you might have checked out into a subfolder of the folder you are looking at.

There is also some caching issues with TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN -> Cleanup usually fixes those.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on a folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Icon overlays -> Status Cache.

Select Shell.

Comment: it works! But can you please explain what exactly it does?

Answer (score 2):

If the repository is located on a network drive, no overlays will be shown.

**EDIT 08. August 2016**
As for TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 on Win10
Right click a folder > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays > Drive Types > mark "Network drives"

Answer (score 1):

Simply renaming my file(From "DEV" to "DEV_") fixed this for me and this was after restarting my computer and  running "Cleanup"

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:

- Run regedit.exe in start/windows.
- open the path, Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
- Delete/Export all OneDrive entries.
- Restart the machine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated Registry key name and keep Tortoise on top of all and it works.. Thanks