# TortoiseHG icons are missing

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've checked my TortoiseHG settings and it's set to show the folder icons showing the status of the files, but I don't see them.  I'm running Windows 7, does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Overlay icons being removed after installing TortoiseHg. The registry icons in  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` were ok but still no icons where showing.

I found out that the icon paths in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseOverlays` for some reason where looking in the folder `CommonFiles\TortoiseOverlays\Icons\MUFWin7` which did not exist.

I don't know how this happened or how this folder was deleted(if it ever existed) but by changing that path I solved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I've had this problem before.  It's important to reboot after freshly installing TortoiseHG (or possibly just logoff and logon again.)

If this doesn't work, then it's possible that you have too many icon overlays types being used by various progams.

This [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7) discussion talks about maxing out icon overlays.

I think the registry entries that TortoiseHG uses in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers are 1TortoiseNomal, 2TortoiseModified, 3TortoiseConflict, etc...

You need to make sure that there aren't too many icon overlays before these.  Of course this could break other overlays!

Comment: I can add to this since I have had to do this at least 5 times in the last year or so...  Make sure also to go to TortoiseHg > Explorer Extension Settings and un-check the icon overlays you delete from the registry ;--)

Answer (score 2):

May be you install some new soft ,so there are so many overlay icons.delete some,reboot explorer.exe.Windows can only show a limited number of Overlay Icons (15 total, 11 after what Windows uses).

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me, and I wasted 2 hours looking for solution.

I ended up rebooting, now the icons are showing.

There is a service `Overlay Icon Server` , make sure it is started once rebooted.