# SVN upgrade working copy

Tags: svn, version, working-copy

I cannot do a SVN commit. I get this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs to be upgraded
svn: Working copy 'C:\.... is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You have to upgrade your subversion client to at least 1.7.

With the command line client, you have to manually upgrade your working copy format by issuing the command `svn upgrade`:

> **Upgrading the Working Copy**
>
> Subversion 1.7 introduces substantial changes to the working copy
>   format. In previous releases of Subversion, Subversion would
>   automatically update the working copy to the new format when a write
>   operation was performed. Subversion 1.7, however, will make this a
>   manual step. Before using Subversion 1.7 with their working copies,
>   users will be required to run a new command, `svn upgrade` to update the
>   metadata to the new format. This command may take a while, and for
>   some users, it may be more practical to simply checkout a new working
>   copy.
>   — [Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-upgrade)

TortoiseSVN will perform the working copy upgrade with the next write operation:

> **Upgrading the Working Copy**
>
> Subversion 1.7 introduces substantial changes to the working copy
>   format. In previous releases, Subversion would automatically update
>   the working copy to the new format when a write operation was
>   performed. Subversion 1.7, however, will make this a manual step.
>
> Before you can use an existing working copy with TortoiseSVN 1.7, you
>   have to upgrade the format first. If you right-click on an old working
>   copy, TortoiseSVN only shows you one command in the context menu:
>   Upgrade working copy.
>   — [TortoiseSVN 1.7 Release notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html)

Comment: When I issue the command `svn upgrade` Ubuntu tells me "command not found"

Comment: @geneorama: do you have `svn` installed? (`sudo apt-get install svn`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did have svn installed (subversion), but it was version 1.6, which does not have the `upgrade` command.  Ubuntu 12.04 wouldn't install 1.7 without adding a new ppa.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-7-binary

Comment: @genorama Here are instructions to upgrade svn for Mac OS that will work if starting from 1.6 http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/update-subversion-mac-os-x . For Linux, I imagine it's similar.

Comment: "This command may take a while, and for some users, it may be more practical to simply checkout a new working copy." I'm running the command don't knowing what to expect, after 2 seconds the console replies upgraded '.' :P

Comment: This is also a helpful URL for those using Subclipse in Eclipse:  [http://benohead.com/use-svn-1-8-eclipse/](http://benohead.com/use-svn-1-8-eclipse/).

Comment: Performing an upgrade for my working copy, what will do server side? Will other users using an old version be able to continue to use their dated version?

Comment: @LucioMenci: other users will not be affected by your local settings

Answer (score 57):

from eclipse, you can select on the project, right click->team->upgrade

Comment: Unable to find upgrade option

Answer (score 6):

On MacOS:

1. Get the latest compiled SVN client binaries from [here](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx).
2. Install.
3. Add binaries to path (the last installation screen explains how).
4. Open terminal and run the following command on your project directory:

> svn upgrade

Answer (score 4):

If you have just upgraded to SVN 1.7 on your machine (like I just did), and have a lot of projects in your Eclipse workspace which need to be upgraded, you can do the following in a terminal window on Unix-baesd systems:

```
cd [eclipse/workspace] # <- you supply the actual path here

for file in `find . -depth 2 -name "*.svn"`; do svn upgrade `dirname $file` ; done;
```

After Googling a bit, I found what seems to be the equivalent for Windows users:

http://www.rqna.net/qna/mnrmqn-how-to-find-all-svn-working-copies-on-win-xp.html

See the answer by Alexey Shcherbak halfway down the page.

Answer (score 2):

This problem due to that you try to compile project that has the files of OLder SVN than you currently use.

You have two solutions to resolve this problem

1. to install the version 1.6  SVN to be compatible with  project SVN files
2. try to upgrade the project  ..( not always working ).

Answer (score 2):

You can also get strange messages about the need to upgrade your working copy when there are other working copies nested into yours. I had this issue with a Symphony project were some framework folders are working copy, that I suppose have not been cleaned up properly before they were published.

In this case, just make a file search for `.svn`, and delete the `.svn` folders that you don't want (don't delete yours at the root of course).

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to the latest version of Tortoise-SVN I needed to do an "Upgrade" first (as opposed to "Update"!).

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error from Netbeans (7.2+) then it means that your separately installed version of Subversion is higher than the version in netbeans. In my case Netbeans (v7.3.1) had SVN v1.7 and I'd just upgraded my SVN to v1.8.

If you look in `Tools > Options > Miscellaneous (tab) > Versioning (tab) > Subversion (pane)`, set the **Preferred Client = CLI**, then you can set the path the the installed SVN which for me was `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`.

More can be found on the [Netbeans Subversion Clients FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionClients#NetBeans_.3E.3D_7.2).

Answer (score 1):

With [AnkhSVN](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/E721D830-7664-4E02-8D03-933C3F1477F2) in Visual Studio, there's also an "Upgrade Working Copy" option under the context menu for the solution in the Solution Explorer (when applicable).

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Subversion 1.7. In order to update to Subversion 1.7 you have to *launch existing project in Xcode 5 or above.* This will prompt an warning ‘`The working copy ProjectName should be upgraded to Subversion 1.7`’ (shown in below screenshot).

[image: Screenshot for warning]

You should select ‘`Upgrade`’ button to upgrade to Subversion 1.7. This will take a bit of time.

If you are using *terminal* then you can upgrade to Subversion 1.7 by running below command in your project directory:  **svn upgrade**

Note that once you have `upgraded to Subversion 1.7 you cannot go back to Subversion 1.6.`

[Refer Apple docs for more details.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/UpgradingtoSubversion1/UpgradingtoSubversion1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013353-CH3-SW1)