# Subclipse on a Mac in a Windows network. Can't Commit - Can't get exclusive lock

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, osc

I have an iMac running OS X 10.7.3. I have Eclipse Indigo and Subclipse 1.8.6 installed. I'm able to connect to and save files to our repository through Finder when I provide proper credentials. I am able even to check out projects. When I make changes to the checked out project, I see the update icon, I can even view conflicts in diff.

The problem occurs when I try to commit code, I am unable to get an exclusive lock, and the commit fails.

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E204899: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E204899: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/Volumes/TECHSUPPORT/SOFTWARE/Java_Projects/db/txn-current-lock': Operation not supported
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E204899: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E204899: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/Volumes/TECHSUPPORT/SOFTWARE/Java_Projects/db/txn-current-lock': Operation not supported
```

I've tried everything I can think of, I've used both available SVN's. There doesn't seem to be much on the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of subversion is installed on your Mac?

```
$ svn --version
```

I think you need to update the program: [SVN upgrade working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy)

Comment: Turns out... SVN was on a Windows file share. Not a good mix. I tried a few utils to let me write to NTFS... fail.
I fixed the problem by getting rid of the FS and putting it on a Linux box, and now it works great for everyone.