# org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException - client is too old

Tags: svn, subclipse

I get the following error message when I try to compare files in Eclipse using Subclipse:

> Unsupported working copy format svn: This client is too old to work with the working copy at 'C:\XXX' (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change.

I'm using, svn (command line): 1.8.0, Subclipse: 1.8.22, Subversion JavaHL: 1.7.10.

What could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN upgrade working copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade Subclipse plugin to [the latest 1.10.x version](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de). Subclipse 1.8.x works with SVN 1.7 and requires to be upgraded to 1.10.x in order to work with SVN 1.8 working copies.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue after updating working copy from Tortoise SVN.

Issue fixed by upgrading Subclipse plugin to latest 1.10.x version. Update performed by searching in Help -> Eclipse Marketplace.