# Unable to commit files in SVN

Tags: svn

I have tortoise SVN with version 1.8.4,Also in eclipse I have Eclipse Neon with subclipse 1.8.22
subversion JavaHL Native Library 1.7.10
svn kit client adaptor 1.7.9.2
While I try to commit files into SVN I am getting below error.Please help!!

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs
>   to be upgraded svn: Working copy 'D:\Checkout\8
>   EIRCODE_BULKUPLOAD\eircodeBulkOperation\src\main\java\com\techm\servcreation\eircodeBulkOperation\dto'
>   is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
>
> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs
>   to be upgraded svn: Working copy 'D:\Checkout\file path' is too old
>   (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

Comment: A similar question has already been asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy

Comment: As both of the submitted duplicated state: Its exactly as your errormessage states: you need to upgrade the working copy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message say. you have to upgrade the working copy by the command line client.

```
svn upgrade [Working Path]
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks much.I upgraded through eclipse.:)