# How to view all revisions in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, logging

The TortoiseSVN "Show Log" option filters the revisions by date. It's cumbersome to alter those dates manually. How to view all revisions with minimal hassle?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You *must* perform this at the root folder of you Repository.

- Uncheck `Stop on copy/rename
- Check `Include merged revisions`
- At the bottom of the show Log dialog box, press the `show all` button.

Doing that will set the date range for you also.

[image]

Depending on the size of your repository this may take awhile.  But you will get a list of every single revision this way.

[image]

Comment: You may need to check or uncheck the bottom two options depending on your exact situation

Comment: Okay, I clicked it, nothing happened, maybe I'm already seeing all revisions. But is there any explanation why does the revisions numbers begin with 58 instead of 0?

Comment: check `include merged revisions` and Uncheck `stop on copy/rename`  It will take longer but you will see all your revisions...I think.

Comment: you'd have to be at the root folder level to see rev 1

Comment: @XMLForDummies: An SVN revision is global to the whole repository. It's incremented at each commit. If some file has been added to the repository at commit 58, then its first revision in its log will be 58.

Comment: I just typed `svn log` at the root but I'm still getting 58 as the first revision number, maybe they stripped older revisions

Answer (score 14):

I'm really sorry but did you try to click Show All button?
Or I misunderstood something

Also you may change the amount of revisions which will be showed at the beginning: 
Settings --> General --> Dialogs 1 --> Default number of messages

Comment: "Settings --> General --> Dialogs 1 --> Default number of messages"
Is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt:

```
svn log
```

Comment: The poster asked specifically how this can be done in TortoiseSVN

Comment: Well it's both tagged "SVN" and "TortoiseSVN", so perhaps the command line option is suitable for the OP.

Comment: When it is tagged just SVN, you cannot talk about TortoiseSVN, but it is not the other way around. When both are tagged, give answer specific to the subset.