# SVN icon overlays not showing properly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm testing SVN. After the configuration, I can add/commit the files successfully.

However, I can't see the status icons on the files and folders. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: In my case I had recently installed DropBox for one specific job. The simple solution was to uninstall DropBox and restart the PC. For an explanation of why this is happening, and instructions on what to do if you want to keep DropBox installed, see the answers below that mention DropBox, especially the one by @TAdrian that indicates a quick way of starting RegEdit at the correct place in the registry.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is, unfortunately a quite common problem on Windows where the icons are either not updated or rather disappearing. I find it quite annoying. It usually is fixed by either refreshing the Windows folder (F5) or, by doing a SVN Clean up,

```
Right click on the folder ->  TortoiseSVN -> Clean up... 
Select Clean up working copy status
```

I have never been able to solve this permanently, this is only a work-around. Keeping TortoiseSVN on the latest version may or may not help.

Note that the clean up will only clean up your local working copy, it wont do anything to the actual repository. Its a safe operation.

---

Apparently this is not enough according to your comment. Do you have lots of other programs that are also using overlay icons? If so maybe you can find a solution in this thread: [TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7)? The second most voted answer also deals with network drives etc. Its a good read.

---

Also, have you rebooted your computer after the install? From the [TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovllostonupgrade):

> You rebooted your PC of course after the installation? If you haven't please do so now. TortoiseSVN is a windows Explorer Shell extension and will be loaded together with Explorer.
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, try doing a repair install (and reboot of course).

Comment: Thank you. I tried Clean up and F5. Neither of the methods works. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Windy: Updated the answer with a useful link that I think can help you.

Comment: @Windy: Added comments from the FAQ as well. Did you reboot?

Comment: Thank you. I've solved the problem by restarting the explorer. :)

Answer (score 48):

In my case, Dropbox overlays were starting with a " (quoted identifier) in the registry. I deleted all the " prefixes and restarted explorer.exe.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

Edit: I installed Windows 10 and this solution didn't work for me. So I just went to the same registry location and deleted all Google and SkyDrive records and restarted explorer.exe.

Second edit: After installing TortoiseGit it fixed everything without any customisation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing " of dropbox Registry keys worked for me and didn't affect dropbox!

Comment: No worries at all. I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. To be clear, you can (and probably should) remove the leading and trailing `"` characters.

Comment: After trying all the other solutions, this worked for me. (Had to restart Explorer or restart PC after doing this, for them to show up.)

Comment: I did all of the above with no joy. Fix for me was after doing those tweaks, restarting, to go to control panel > apps, Tortoise SVN, Modify, repair install.  After that it started to work again. (Windows 10 64bit)

Answer (score 38):

To fix this go to TortoiseSVN > settings > Icon Overlays > Status cache changed from default to shell.

If the drive A or B is used check the Drive type as A and B.

Comment: Worked for me and some of my coworkers.
One thing though : Tortoise had to be upgraded to the latest version in order to work with your workaround.
Anyway, cheers mate!!!

Comment: This worked for me TortoiseSVN > settings > Icon Overlays > Status cache changed from default to shell. then restart windows explorer.

Comment: The reverse of this suggestion worked for me. SVN was previously configured for "shell", but was erroneously showing green on all folders. changing back to "default" fixed it.

Comment: Changing Status Cache from default to shell worked for me. Windows 10, TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 Build 21511 - 64 Bit

Comment: NOTE: If you have DropBox, Google Drive, or OneDrive installed, this won't help; instead see the answers that talk about editing registry entries: its not possible to have more than one app show its status, so if you really want TortoiseSVN to show, you'll have to make those be alphabetically first (Rename each entry - add several spaces at start of name).

Answer (score 16):

The problem I was having is that drop box was putting its overlays in at a higher priority than SVN

They both put spaces on the beginning of the entries to push them to the top of the list in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
>   Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\

The following article explains this more fully and shows how to fix it.

https://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit/

However as dropbox gets updated relativity frequently on my machine, and I rarely update Tortoise SVN I would suggest just appending spaces to the tortoise entries to push them up the list, otherwise you'll have to do all this again when a dropbox software update is installed.

Answer (score 13):

Following are steps :

1. Run “regedit” and locate:
   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
   Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\"
2. rename the folders in order you want  (trick use 01_, 02_ as prefixes)
3. terminate explorer.exe from task manager and re-run explorer.exe task.

You will see that overlays are shown where you did not see them initially as per preferences given

Answer (score 10):

in my case, the tortoise icon not showing at all,
I tried this and solved my problem :

1. open registry
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
3. delete all folder OneDrive
4. delete all folder SkyDrive

(the point is to place all tortoise folder at top)

5. open TaskManager and kill Explorer
6. re run Explorer through TaskManager

Answer (score 5):

I met this problem with TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN. DropBox renamed its registry entry with more white spaces as prefix "  " than I did for Tortoise.

Tortoise directly can open the registry editor by 
*TortoiseGit > Settings > Icon Overlays > Overlay Handlers* there click *Start registry editor* and rename entries so that the first in alphabetical order to be what you want.

Comment: NOTE: TortoiseSVN has the same option, at the same menu path (but starting with TortoiseSVN of course): *TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays > Overlay Handlers / Start registry editor*.  See also Sprotty's answer, specifically *"... appending spaces to the tortoise entries to push them up the list, otherwise you'll have to do all this again when a dropbox software update is installed."*

Comment: Unfortunately, Dropbox update will just add more spaces than what you put for Tortoise entries.

Comment: ahh, you mean it actually looks at what is there, and adds however many spaces are necessary to be in front??  That is evil. [A very minor evil, but still...] I was hoping once it had been installed, it wouldn't touch those entries on an update.

Answer (score 3):

My overlays disappeared all of a sudden (or so I thought).  I came across this article https://corengen.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/my-tortoisesvn-icon-overlays-have-disappeared/ which points out that windows has 15 slots for overlay icons; 4 are reserved for windows, which leaves 11 for other applications.   Regardless of how many overlay keys are in the registry, Windows selects the first 11 in alphabetical order.

When I upgraded Office, OneDrive added overlay icons -- prefixed with a lot of spaces -- pushing down Tortoise's overlays below the threshold:  [windows registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcojJ.png)  Since I am not using OneDrive, the solution was to add a "z" to the OneDrive key names.

Comment: Thank you, just installed oneDrive and that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem, like [Avada Kedavra said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069928/3738405), actually, this is documented [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html), in the section "Icon Overlay Settings", and I also show bellow. You can read that, and choose the one you like most.

> Since it takes quite a while to fetch the status of a working copy,
>   TortoiseSVN uses a cache to store the status so the explorer doesn't
>   get hogged too much when showing the overlays. You can choose which
>   type of cache TortoiseSVN should use according to your system and
>   working copy size here:
>
> Default
>
> Caches all status information in a separate process
>   (TSVNCache.exe). That process watches all drives for changes and
>   fetches the status again if files inside a working copy get modified.
>   The process runs with the least possible priority so other programs
>   don't get hogged because of it. That also means that the status
>   information is not real time but it can take a few seconds for the
>   overlays to change.
>
> **Advantage:** the overlays show the status recursively, i.e. if a file
>   deep inside a working copy is modified, all folders up to the working
>   copy root will also show the modified overlay. And since the process
>   can send notifications to the shell, the overlays on the left tree
>   view usually change too.
>
> **Disadvantage:** the process runs constantly, even if you're not working
>   on your projects. It also uses around 10-50 MB of RAM depending on
>   number and size of your working copies.
>
> **Shell**
>
> Caching is done directly inside the shell extension dll, but
>   only for the currently visible folder. Each time you navigate to
>   another folder, the status information is fetched again.
>
> **Advantage:** needs only very little memory (around 1 MB of RAM) and can
>   show the status in real time.
>
> **Disadvantage:** Since only one folder is cached, the overlays don't show
>   the status recursively. For big working copies, it can take more time
>   to show a folder in explorer than with the default cache. Also the
>   mime-type column is not available.
>
> **None**
>
> With this setting, the TortoiseSVN does not fetch the status at
>   all in Explorer. Because of that, files don't get an overlay and
>   folders only get a 'normal' overlay if they're versioned. No other
>   overlays are shown, and no extra columns are available either.
>
> **Advantage:** uses absolutely no additional memory and does not slow down
>   the Explorer at all while browsing.
>
> **Disadvantage:** Status information of files and folders is not shown in
>   Explorer. To see if your working copies are modified, you have to use
>   the “Check for modifications” dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise SVN on Windows happens to lose sync quite often with the real file status.
In that case try doing an `svn cleanup`.

Another thing, it may also depend where your source files are located, different drive, network drive, etc. There's an option in Tortoise to allow icon overlay or not, on remote drives.

Check this out in:
*TortoiseSVN* / *Settings* / *Icon Overlays* / *Drive types*

Comment: I'm using the "Fixed Drives" option. And I assume it is correct, right. And the clean up doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved the problem by restarting the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

First clear the temporary files in Windows system, then restart your system.

Run > `%temp%` > delete all files

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem when I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. Eventually I have to re-install SVN and reboot the system and it worked. However, I have to manually upgrade each SVN directory to new SVN 1.8 format (it showed up automatically on explorer on right click to upgrade the directory to latest version). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, just open **Settings** of TortoiseSVN, and expand **Icon Overlays**, select **Icon Set** and change the icon set.

The default icon set of mine is **XP Style**, and I change it to **Win10** because Win10 is the OS I am currently using.

[image: The setting]

Restart your computer and problem gets solved.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the underlying issue -- I tried this on Windows 10 and no luck despite the relevant folder being an SVN repo.

Comment: It worked for me, but I must say that I had previously re-ordered the entries in the windows registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Explorer \ ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

Answer (score 0):

In my case all icons suddenly disappeared .

Solution :

1. Go To Task Manager and kill Explorer
2. In Task Manager File (New Task
       (Run) ) => explorer

and all appeared again...

Answer (score 0):

Simply closing my file explorer using task manager and then running it again fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

OR You can also just use the command line interface CMD in Windows.
I know, it's not the GUI (even I like to use the graphical user interface usually ), however, it's just two lines!!!

SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM LIKE THIS:

1- Run the command line interface (CMD) as an administrator.

2- Change to the proper disk drive, by typing the drive letter with a colon ( ex: "D:", "E:", or like mine is "W:" ). Then "cd" to your local repository directory ( mine is W:\svn\internet ) then execute these lines :

```
W:\>svn cleanup

W:\svn\internet>svn up
```

That way, you'll know for sure that it's up to date. You won't even need an icon to tell you that!