# TortoiseSVN not showing red exclamation mark(!) on folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

It was working before but suddenly it stops showing the red exclamation mark(!) on folders that have their files modified and not committed yet. Instead the folders are showing green check mark regardless of whether their files are uncommitted or committed. That's kind of annoying since now I have to open each and every folder of the project to find out if it has any file or files that need to be committed. We don't want to commit the entire project folder since some of the files need to wait for a commit as work on them is in progress. **Note**: There are many posts online for the related issue but all that I found describe issue in reverse, i.e. files are committed but folder is showing red exclamation mark(!) on itself. Please note my case is quite the opposite

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069928/1620112

Comment: Windows sometimes take some time to update the icon. You can always use `Check For Modifications` to quickly see what have changed inside your working copy. Anyway, I would not rely on these icons since it might happen than the another installation overwrites some of these icons as their number is limited by Windows