# SVN still showing modified?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a couple of projects that are showing the "modified" icon, I've checked the contents of the top project folders and all the files in the folders have normal icon, no other icons are showing, any subfolders in these folders I have already added the contents to the exclude list.

Why are the parent folders still showing the "modified" status, I've performed updates on these folders from the top several times.

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Did you run the `svn status` command from the top-level folder ? Or could it be a svn property of these top project folders that is locally modified ? Did you perform the `Check for modifications...` on these folders using TortoiseSVN ? Did you try to run the `Clean up` command ?

Comment: This is TortoiseSVN, what command do I run, tried: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn", doesn't like that

Comment: ty, sorted, Check for modifications highlighted a difference that wasn't visible in file explorer.

Comment: Which kind of difference did it show you (text or property ?) ? Is your problem fully solved now ?

Comment: It is solved but I don’t know why the difference wasn’t visible in the file explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the icons in file explorer are not updated properly is a common issue widely observed by users for many reasons, see for example [Windows Explorer icons in TortoiseSVN take a long time to refresh to correct state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217880/windows-explorer-icons-in-tortoisesvn-take-a-long-time-to-refresh-to-correct-sta), or also here
[SVN icon overlays not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069772/svn-icon-overlays-not-showing-properly). You can find yourself many other posts discussing about this issue.

To solve it I suggest you to:

- perform a `Clean up` command with TortoiseSVN from the top-level folders
- use the `Check for modifications...` using TortoiseSVN to be sure to see the modifications if any

In any case, don't blindly rely on the icons.