# TortoiseSVN missing overlays in win8

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've recently installed a fresh win8 copy. After installing tortoiseSVN, it does recognize the folders as being under version control (the menu items are there), but no overlays on the icons.
I Checked the registry settings as described here: [TortoiseSVN icons not showing up under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7)
But the first 9 entries are all for tortoiseSVN and there are 4 others, so no problems there.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to restart Windows after TortoiseSVN installation?

Comment: Had you any success? I have the same problem. Restart windows/cleanup/restart explorer/restart windows. and the problem is still there.

Comment: Try it http://www.sitepoint.com/missing-tortoisesvn-file-status-overlay-icons/

Comment: If these solutions don't work, you might have more than 15 overlay icons registered, see here http://superuser.com/questions/542116/why-are-icon-overlays-from-3rdparty-apps-not-showing-up-in-the-win8-explorer

Answer (score 8):

Go to regedit. Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers.
Add space before folders, example: "1TortoiseNormal" -> " 1TortoiseNormal".
Restart computer.
Works for me.

Comment: Could you please explain what this exactly does? Fiddling with your registry can be quite dangerous.

Comment: Windows reads only 11 positions from folder "ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers". Thanks to that modification tortoise elements will be before OneDrive1...5 elements.
I recommend make a copy of your register.

Comment: This solution is strange. You rocked it man! Thank you so much. Once again, would you please explain why that worked? Thank you.

Comment: It works because Windows processes the elements in ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers in alpha-sort order, and it stops when it has as many as it allows.  The folks at OneDrive obviously know this, because *their* entries start with a single space.  So now my TortoiseSvn entries start with *two* spaces.  Let the space wars begin!

Comment: works for me. [restart explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2052946/339874) instead of a reboot for quicker testing.

Comment: Works. Had " SkyDrive???" as the first 4 entries on my work computer. Put two spaces in front of all the Tortoise entries.

Answer (score 7):

Go to TortoiseSVN > settings > Icon Overlays > Status cache changed from default to shell.

If the drive A, B or network is used check that drivew

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

Sometimes you just have to restart Windows (if not already done).

You could also have to do a "Cleanup" (right click, Tortoise SVN shell entry) of your working copy, and to check "Refresh shell overlays" in the window.

Also, please review "Icon overlays" tab of Tortoise settings (right click, Tortoise SVN shell entry, Settings)  settings of your tortoise SVN, especially if your working copy is (for example) on amovible or network drive.

Comment: This fixed it for me when I had problems with outdated and missing overlay icons in some places and not others.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I was working on a network drive. By default, Tortoise doesn't show icons on network drives.

To enable the icons on other types of drive, right-click in Windows Explorer and go to:

`TortoiseSVN --> Icon Overlays --> Drive Types`

This may also solve the problem in other cases, where other drives are in use and not showing icons for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do an svn actualization (in my case a fully checkout). just restart the explorer (or computer) after configure the registry did not show the overlay icons in my case

Comment: @haxenmaxen, thank! This is working, I wonder why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the registry, tsvn clean up etc did not help anything.

Solved it by killing the process 'TortoiseSVN status cache' in task manager. Icons reappeared one by one after that.

In TSVN settings I've set the Status Cache to default (was None initially), but not sure this had anything to do with it. Also restarted explorer.exe to be sure.

I had an older/non-compatible version (1.6) of TSVN installed before updating to latest (1.8.8). This could have been part of the problem.