# svn check mark and +(plus) symbol is missing after committing and adding a file

Tags: svn

I have installed the latest versions of visual svn server and tortoise svn on my windows 8 machine.

when i am working with my server if i do commit it is getting committed and while adding a file it is adding .The problem is while i am adding a file to my working copy it is not showing the +(plus) symbol, and after getting commit it is not showing the checking mark green colour. I tried all the possible ways to fix it but i cannot succeed. can you please help me ..Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else do you see against those files?

Comment: nothing.It just like a plain .txt file if i modify or commit .It is getting committing and modifiying but it is not showing the marks and symbols on it. It very hard to work with Svn without the symbols.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/) is related?

Comment: i already gone through it but it is not related to that.

Comment: @mystarrocks thank you i resolved it by the link that which u have provided .